# Transitively import foo._ in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm using a utility library for dimensional analysis that i'd like to extend with my own units, and I'd like to be able to write

```
import my.util.units._
```

in files in my project. My thought was to define

```
package my.util

object units {
  import squants._
  [... other definitions ...]
}
```

and I expected `import my.util.units._` to have the same effect as `import squants._`, plus the other definitions. But it seems importing `units._` doesn't end up adding `squants._` to the scope.

Is there a way to do this in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've dealt with this a little bit at work, and we've tried to resolve this a few ways. Here's an example of how we import rabbitmq types throughout [scala-amqp](https://github.com/BostonTechnologies/scala-amqp/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/bostontechnologies/amqp/package.scala):

```
package com.bostontechnologies

package object amqp {

  type RabbitShutdownListener = com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownListener
  type RabbitConnection = com.rabbitmq.client.Connection
  type RabbitChannel = com.rabbitmq.client.Channel
  type RabbitConsumer = com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer
  type RabbitAddress = com.rabbitmq.client.Address

  ...
}
```

So now when we import `com.bostontechnologies.amqp._` we get access to the rabbitmq types that we've defined. I know it requires quite a bit of duplication, however we've found it to be somewhat useful, especially since it gives us granularity over type names.

Also, you don't need to use a package object, we mainly use it for convenience of automatically importing our types around a package. You could just use a normal object as well.

Comment: In fact, this pattern can be seen [in scala core itself](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4223bc2ddc497457c7dccd1b9b65e98244a9b4d1/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L94)

Answer (score 3):

Imports are not transitive in Java or Scala.  Probably the closest you are going to get to what you seek is to create an object (perhaps a package object) with a `type` definition for each type of interest.